# Xamarin forms listview databinding to object

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to bind to an object rather than the properties in a list view. For example:

```
public ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(); 
        public EmployeeListPage()
        {                      
            employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Rob Finnerty" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Bill Wrestler" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Dr. Geri-Beth Hooper" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Dr. Keith Joyce-Purdy" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Sheri Spruce" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Burt Indybrick" });       
        }

 <ListView ItemSource="{Binding employees}" x:Name="emView">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
              <b:CustomView Employee="{Binding .}"/>
          </ViewCell>                   
        </DataTemplate>                     
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>`
```

Comment: Of course! In fact, from the first look of things the code you are posting should work. So what is your actual question?

Comment: Its not working. `Employee="{Binding .}"` is a custom BindableProperty

Comment: If we are to figure out what is wrong we also need to see the code for that then

Comment: Here is the code (http://pastebin.com/RYVinwEz)

Comment: You don't seem to have any PropertyChanged logic, so maybe it is updated but higher up it is never notified? Did you put breakpoints in? Do they get hit?

Comment: You could try to fill temporary collection with your items and then `employees = new ObservableCollection(tempEmployees)`. It will raise collection change. Also I would add `EmptyConverter` and will look if `{Binding employees}` works. And then I would check what I'm getting from `{Binding .}`.